# How can I use X509SecurityKey for Asp.Net Core JWT validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

How can I (can I?) use X509SecurityKey for Asp.Net Core JWT validation?

My current code is roughly:

```
        X509SecurityKey signingKey = null;

        using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var v = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, true);
            var v1 = v.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, strCertName, true);
            signingKey = new X509SecurityKey(v1[0]);
        }
```

and later on for the signing credentials...

```
new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
```

This causes an exception:

SignatureAlgorithm: 'HS256', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey'
 is not supported.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm)

I tried a few algorithms, but it doesn't seem like it works with any of them?

Comment: See similar issue https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/61 It seems the problem is about signature algorithm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I tried a few algorithms, but it doesn't seem like it works with any of them?

You're trying to use an asymmetric key (embedded in a X.509 certificate) with a HMAC algorithm (that we often *abusively* call "symmetric signature algorithm"): this cannot work.

Assuming your certificate is a RSA certificate, you should be able to use `SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256`.

```
var credentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with RsaSha512. I also had to recreate the cert with an embedded private key.

Comment: @PinPoint I have a similiar question, mind helping me out over there please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294373/net-core-issuersigningkey-from-file-for-jwt-bearer-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I had mistakenly set:

```
TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = false,
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
    ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer,
    ValidAudiences = jwtSettings.Audiences,
    IssuerSigningKey = SymmetricSecurityKey,
    ValidAlgorithms = new string[] { SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature },
    NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name
};
```

Once I removed the ValidAlgorithms configuration option, it resolved the issue.